# How do I check whether the scrollbar is at the beginning or end?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I check whether the scrollbar is at the beginning or end with jquery? For the beginning part i would check if `$(window).scrollTop <= 0`, but what should i use for the end?

Thank you

Comment: You should be using `$(window).scrollTop() <= 0` in your code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height())
```